Parent -> child wobbling, witching, shaking inverse kinematics
When I was simulating a car using the Launch Control addon, I noticed that the parented driver (a character) does not follow the animated car correctly, shaking intensely. A similar phenomenon occurs when I parent the camera to the car; it also starts to vibrate when the model it follows is animated. How can I avoid this error? Are there any iteration options for the parent -> child relationship in Blender?
GIF example
File example with complex rig
Video example with simplified rig

hello could you please share a file where it happens?

sure, here you go. Check how camera reacts to animated object, it's shaking.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QEQBA082Cgx2kBIJpJMo44B8CNnnZNux/view?usp=sharing

Look through one of the cameras and you will see that either of them is slightly vibrating. Zoom in if needed.

maybe it is struggling with micro rotations, maybe remove the action, keep your car aligned with the global rotation, animate it going straight ahead, parent the car to an empty and tilt the empty? Or make it follow a curve?

Originally car is led by a curve. Then whole animation is baked. And when attaching things to baked animation they start to vibrate.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RE9zcYg3GlQ3xb61FwlLcK-zSMoZKbkf/view?usp=sharing

I may be wrong but it may be a problem of calculation, do you really need to bake the action?

I will have few interior shots with driver in so yes.

I'm not sure why having a driver makes you bake the action?

I'm testing different solutions I find on the internet, and here are my thoughts. First and foremost when I animate car with just a simple noise (for rotation and Z transformation only) this problem does not occur ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2MG2AthnbA&list=PLvIzXTWjF_T52Ai61e15FzlH0QfBUOW1V&index=4&ab) but as soon as I parent the car to a curve rig goes crazy (twitching). I also noticed, that when I move rig's hips without playback the IK hands that rest on steering wheel (and are connected to it via Child of constraint) also twitch. It's like Blender have problems with calculations.

Here is the clearer example of my problem  https://drive.google.com/file/d/15WRUm73D2h97oHyAL65LrEwgvJMTelac/view?usp=sharing

Ok, I changed rig from auto rig pro to super duper easy rig with only IK for hands that hold rotating steering wheel. I also enabled wiggly bones, but that is totally not the case and don't cause any problems in this case. So the character rig is super easy and still, when I parent IK hands to empties on a steering wheel the hands shake (very very annoying and unnatural. I imagine this is all about inacurate calculations for the IK made by blender but how to fix/avoid it? Here's example of the wobbling https://youtu.be/0KG5LPCDJAM

It appears that the farther from the center of the scene the less correct are the child-parent calculations. Had to move the entire scene closer to the center, and problem dissapeared. Ufff....
